# Combine and nested JSON objects

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have the following model:

```
struct Book: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var author: String
}

struct BookWrapper: Codable {
    var books: [Book]

}
```

and JSON:

```
{
  "books": [
    {
        "id":     1,
        "title":  "Nineteen Eighty-Four: A Novel",
        "author": "George Orwell"
    }, {
        "id":     2,
        "title":  "Animal Farm",
        "author": "George Orwell"
    }
  ],
  "errMsg": null
}
```

I'm trying to grab data using Combine, but cannot find a way how to go around that books array. In case of *flat* data I would use following:

```
func fetchBooks() {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map{ $0.data }
            .decode(type: [Book].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .replaceError(with: [])
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: &$books)
    }
```

I tried to use BookWrapper.self, but it doesn't make sense. Is there any elegant way how to solve it?

Comment: Unrelated but `eraseToAnyPublisher()` makes no sense in this context (no return value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `map` the `books` property of `BooksWrapper` before it gets to your `assign`:

```
func fetchBooks() {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map{ $0.data }
        .decode(type: BookWrapper.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .replaceError(with: BookWrapper(books: [])) //<-- Here
        .map { $0.books }  //<-- Here
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .assign(to: &$books)
}
```

Comment: It certainly works, but I have no idea what's going on there. Could you point me to any doc which can explain what you did?

Comment: The only significant thing added is the map function — you could look at the documentation for it. It’s a good thing to get familiar with if using combine. It takes an input and transforms it to a different output. In this case the input is the BooksWrapper and the output is just the books property.